# How to print specific years on a massive csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

```
import pandas

fileref = open('chart.csv')
f = pandas.read_csv(fileref)

f_set = f[f.year >= 2005]
print(f_set.groupby('y').namefromchart.nunique())
```

So I know `f_set` will print out my y cells with the corresponding years of 2005 through current. What if I want to print out the years 2002 through 2009?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need add second condition to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd

f = pd.read_csv('chart.csv')
f_set = f[(f.year >= 2002) & (f.year < 2010)]
print (f_set.groupby('y').namefromchart.nunique())
```

Another solution with [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html), by default is *inclusive*:

```
f_set = f[f.year.between(2002,2009)]
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the `pd.DataFrame` `f`

```
f = pd.DataFrame(dict(year=range(2000, 2011), A=np.random.rand(11)))
```

you can set the index and slice how you'd like

```
f.set_index('year').ix[2002:2009]
```

[image]